# "bazel version" command error: couldn't connect to server (1657) after 120 seconds

Tags: bazel

I ran the command "bazel version" and got the following error. It worked before and suddenly it doesn't work. What could be the cause of the error?

```
Bazelisk version: v1.7.5
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
... still trying to connect to local Bazel server after 10 seconds ...
... still trying to connect to local Bazel server after 20 seconds ...
... still trying to connect to local Bazel server after 30 seconds ...
... still trying to connect to local Bazel server after 40 seconds ...
... still trying to connect to local Bazel server after 50 seconds ...
... still trying to connect to local Bazel server after 60 seconds ...
... still trying to connect to local Bazel server after 70 seconds ...
... still trying to connect to local Bazel server after 80 seconds ...
... still trying to connect to local Bazel server after 90 seconds ...
... still trying to connect to local Bazel server after 100 seconds ...
... still trying to connect to local Bazel server after 110 seconds ...
FATAL: couldn't connect to server (1657) after 120 seconds.
```

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Is the Bazel server running currently? What is the output of `ps -aux | grep bazel`?

Answer (score 0):

Bazel has a client and a server. If you call `bazel version` you talk to the Bazel client. The Bazel client tries to start the Bazel server (when it's not running already). Maybe the Bazel server executable is broken for some reason.

Delete your local cache (Bazel server), e.g. when using Ubuntu:

```
sudo rm -rf  /home/your_user_name/.cache/bazel
```

Under macOS

```
sudo rm -rf /private/var/tmp/_bazel_your_user_name
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using Ubuntu, after deleting the local cache, I am still seeing the issue.